# Thread killing by name

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

I have a problem with my thread...

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new ThreadStart(delegate {}));
Thread.Sleep(90);
```

It starts and works fine but like forever, and I don't want to run this thread forever.
Is there possible way to give to this thread a name so I can kill it by name in any time I want?
I tried kill it with:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.thread.Abort();
```

but it kill's whole app... 
Basically...
I have a custom combo in my WPF app... this thread is in while loop, when I open the combo starts a loop while(!context.IsClosed) but when its closed, it still runs in background

Comment: That's because you are killing the *main* thread. You invoked a delegate on the UI thread itself and then killed it. What are you trying to do? Why don't you start a background thread with `Task.Run`?

Comment: What is it precisely your trying to do? The dispatcher in a normal wpf or windows app is the main thread. So killing it would kill your app. Maybe you want ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem?

Comment: Do you realise that using the `Dispatcher` in this way doesn't actually *create* a thread?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I didn't really understand your point about `Task.Run`

Comment: So, there is no way to kill it by name?

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding of multithreading approach is completely wrong.

First of all, no, there is no way to give a name to your thread being invoked in such way.
Second, killing a thread is a completely wrong approach in the situations like this, there is easy way to do such things: [`CancellationToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.aspx). You can use some [overloads for the `Dispatcher.Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx) with them (either using the start timeout or not), like this:

[`Dispatcher.Invoke Method (Action, DispatcherPriority, CancellationToken)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh199379.aspx):

```
CancellationTokenSource s = new CancellationTokenSource();
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() => YourMethodHere(), DispatcherPriority.Background, s.Token);
Thread.Sleep(90);

s.Cancel();
```

After calling the [`Cancel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321955.aspx) method the .NET will automatically stop your thread.

Second possible approach, as written in comments, is to use [TPL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) for this, without using the `Thread` creation, something like this (code from [MSDN article about `SynchronizationContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx)):

```
  // This TaskScheduler captures SynchronizationContext.Current.
  TaskScheduler taskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
  // Start a new task (this uses the default TaskScheduler, 
  // so it will run on a ThreadPool thread).
  Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
    // We are running on a ThreadPool thread here.
    // Do some work.
    // Report progress to the UI.
     Task reportProgressTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
       {
         // We are running on the UI thread here.
         // Update the UI with our progress.
       }, 
      s.Token, 
      TaskCreationOptions.None,
      taskScheduler);
    reportProgressTask.Wait();

    // Do more work.
  });
```